# Find out if file has changed

Tags: shell, unix, find, boolean

I want to find out if a file has been modified since the last time my shell script was started, maybe by creating a boolean or something...
Maybe it would be possible to save the last time the script was run in a text file and when the script is started the next time it should read this file and then it should find out what file have been changed so that I can check if a file has changed using something like:

```
for file in *
do
    #Somecode here
    if [ $filehaschanged != "0" ]; then
    echo "Foobar" > file.txt
    fi
    #Somecode here
done
```

Maybe it would be possible to do this with `find`...any ideas?

Comment: Check this: http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/21951-script-view-files-based-date.html

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Michael, by "changed", are you asking if the file has been touched (i.e. datestamp is newer), or are you asking if the content is different?

If the former, you can test this with `find` or `test`.  For example, in shell:

```
#!/bin/sh
touch file1
sleep 1
touch file2
if [ "file1" -nt "file2" ]; then
  echo "This will never be seen."
else
  echo "Sure enough, file1 is older."
fi
```

If what you're looking for is a test of the contents, then your operating system probably includes something that will test the hash of a file.

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ date > testfile
[ghoti@pc ~]$ md5 testfile
MD5 (testfile) = 1b2faf8be02641f37e6d87b15444417d
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cksum testfile
3778116869 29 testfile
[ghoti@pc ~]$ sha1 testfile 
SHA1 (testfile) = 5f4076a3828bc23a050be4867549996180c2a09a
[ghoti@pc ~]$ sha256 testfile
SHA256 (testfile) = f083afc28880319bc31417c08344d6160356d0f449f572e78b343772dcaa72aa
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

I'm in FreeBSD.  If you're in Linux, then you probably have "md5sum" instead of "md5".

To put this into a script, you'd need to walk through your list of files, store their hashes, then have a mechanism to test current files against their stored hashes.  This is easy enough to script:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ find /bin -type f -exec md5 {} \; > /tmp/md5list
[ghoti@pc ~]$ head -5 /tmp/md5list
MD5 (/bin/uuidgen) = 5aa7621056ee5e7f1fe26d8abb750e7a
MD5 (/bin/pax) = 7baf4514814f79c1ff6e5195daadc1fe
MD5 (/bin/cat) = f1401b32ed46802735769ec99963a322
MD5 (/bin/echo) = 5a06125f527c7896806fc3e1f6f9f334
MD5 (/bin/rcp) = 84d96f7e196c10692d5598a06968b0a5
```

You can store this (instead of /bin run it against whatever's important, perhaps `/`) in a predictable location, then write a quick script to check a file against the hash:

```
#!/bin/sh

sumfile=/tmp/md5list

if [ -z "$1" -o ! -f "$1" ]; then
  echo "I need a file."
  exit 1
elif ! grep -q "($1)" $sumfile; then
  echo "ERROR: Unknown file: $1."
  exit 1
fi

newsum="`md5 $1`"

if grep -q "$newsum" $sumfile; then
  echo "$1 matches"
else
  echo "$1 IS MODIFIED"
fi
```

This kind of script is what tools like [tripwire](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tripwire/) provide.

Answer (score 3):

You can **`touch`** all files when you run your script. Then **`touch`** the script itself.
Next time, you just **`find`** any files which is newer than your script.

Comment: Brilliant Idea <3 but how to implement this? `touch myscript.sh | touch * | find ???`

Comment: Ya, that's a clever idea, except that in a larger system with reasonable security set up, the user running a script probably should not have permissions to modify the script, or its timestamp.  To be more portable/secure about this, I'd recommending touching a file in /tmp or /var/tmp that would act as the time comparison.

Comment: @MichealPerr Just put the **`touch`** command at the end of your script

Comment: Inside a script, `$0` is the name of the script.  So if you want to use this approach, you can just add `touch "$0"` to the end of the script.  (The quotes are in case you decide to put funny characters like spaces into your script's filename. It's always a good idea to wrap variables in quotes, inside shell scripts.)

Answer (score 1):

kev's solution in Python, works if you have permissions to touch the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python 
import os
import sys

files= ('a.txt', 'b.txt')
me= sys.argv[0]
mytime= os.path.getmtime(me)
for f in files:
    ft= os.path.getmtime(f)
    if ft > mytime:
        print f, "changed"
os.utime(me, None)
```

Answer (score 1):

After a fair bit of research, it seems like a portable way to make use of timestamps to determine if files have been changed is challenging. `ls` is portable but tricky to parse. `stat` is not portable. In the end, @kev's answer to use a file as a point of reference combined with `find` seems to be the best method I've found so far. I'll contribute to the discussion by providing a few examples to demonstrate how to do this.

### find -newer

This first example demonstrates how `find`'s `-newer` argument works:

```
$ touch a
$ touch b

# Note that b is newer than a. Thus:
$ find b -newer a
b

# a is the same age as a, so it isn't printed here:
$ find a -newer a
$
```

### Application of find -newer

Applying this behavior, we can determine what files were touched by an invocation of a script like so:

```
# Create the reference file:
touch /tmp/some_file

# Now run a script that may touch certain files in ./dir:
./touch_some_files_in_a_directory.sh ./dir

# Find all files in ./dir modified since /tmp/some_file was touched.
find ./dir -newer /tmp/some_file
```

I've been able to use `find` with `-newer` on Linux systems and MacOS. I can't speak to whether this works on other platforms.