# Avoid linking and compiling in Make if not needed

Tags: c++, compilation, linker, makefile

As a follow-up question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31163321/call-make-from-script-only-if-main-c-is-modified/): My Makefile will do the linking, even if nothing is changed in the code. Why? How can I avoid that behaviour, so that `make` won't do anything if the code has not changed?

```
OBJS    = main_no_mkl.o
SOURCE  = main_no_mkl.cpp
HEADER =    IO.h
OUT     =       test
CXX     = ../../mpich-install/bin/mpic++
CXXFLAGS    =   -I../../intel/mkl/include   -Wl,--start-group    -Wl,--end-group    -lpthread   -lm -ldl    -Wall
LDFLAGS   =       ../../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_scalapack_lp64.a       -Wl,--start-group       ../../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_intel_lp64.a ../../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_core.a  ../../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_sequential.a    -Wl,--end-group ../../intel/mkl/lib/intel64/libmkl_blacs_intelmpi_lp64.a -lpthread       -lm     -ldl

all: $(OBJS)
    $(CXX)  $(OBJS) -o  $(OUT)  $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

# create/compile the individual files >>separately<<
main_no_mkl.o:    main_no_mkl.cpp
    $(CXX)  -c  main_no_mkl.cpp $(CXXFLAGS)

.PHONY : all
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is your `all` target. It doesn't generate an `all` (and is marked `.PHONY` as well) file. Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2145605/2411320) for a reminder about `.PHONY`. (You are violating the second [Rule of Makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/).)

So the second/etc time you run `make` (assume the `.PHONY` marking wasn't present) make would look for an `all` file, not find it, and assume it must need to create it again.

With `.PHONY` you short-circuit that file-finding logic and make just **always** assumes it needs to run the recipe again.

So, essentially, you've told make to **always** run the linking step so make does that.

Use this instead to fix that problem.

```
all: $(OUT)

$(OUT): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX)  $(OBJS) -o  $(OUT)  $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

For the record running `make -d` and reading through the output would have pointed this out to you.

Comment: Succinct, clear, useful. Wonderful answer. Thanks for your contribution.

Answer (score 2):

The objects are really the dependencies of your output, and your "all" target should depend on the output(s). So you should do something like this instead:

```
all: $(OUT)

$(OUT): $(OBJS)
    $(CXX)  $(OBJS) -o  $(OUT)  $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
```

Comment: Javier thanks for the answer. However, I fail to see how it differs from Etan's.

Comment: It's actually the same, we just wrote our answers at the same time :-)